# VizFrame Error Message: 50014 - Feed Failed Tests could not accept more data containers

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a table in SAPUI5, and I am getting the following error message:

[50014] - Feed Failed Tests could not accept more data containers

I am creating my line graph as follows:

In View.js:

```
    var lineGraph = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame("graphID", {
         vizProperties: {
            title: {
               text: 'Title'
            }
         }
});

var panel4 = new sap.m.Panel({
            headerText:"sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame",
            expandable: true,
            expanded: true,
            content:[lineGraph]
        });
```

In controller.js:

```
    var oVizFrame = sap.ui.getCore().byId("graphID");
    var oDataSet = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [{
            name: "components",
            value: "{name}"}],
        measures: [{
            name: "Failed Tests",
            value: "{coverage}"}],
        data: {
            path: ""
        }
    });
    oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataSet);
    oVizFrame.setModel(oModel); 
    oVizFrame.setVizType('line');
    oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
        plotArea: {
            colorPalette : d3.scale.category20().range()
            }});

    var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "valueAxis",
          'type': "Measure",
          'values': ["products"]
        }), 
        feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "categoryAxis",
          'type': "Dimension",
          'values': ["Failed Tests"]
        });
    oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis);
    oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis);
```

I havent found a reason for this error message yet, and I was wondering if anyone would be familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

When I faced the same issues and try to find an answer, this post was the first one in the search. But there is no answer. It took me some time to debug why the error occurs. It seems that ui5 needs names of FlattenedDataset and values of FeedItem to have exactly same names/spelling. I fixed my issues by fixing the names. For the question above the correct answer should be:

```
var oVizFrame = sap.ui.getCore().byId("graphID");
var oDataSet = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
        name: "products",
        value: "{name}"}],
    measures: [{
        name: "Failed Tests",
        value: "{coverage}"}],
    data: {
        path: ""
    }
});
oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataSet);
oVizFrame.setModel(oModel); 
oVizFrame.setVizType('line');
oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    plotArea: {
        colorPalette : d3.scale.category20().range()
        }});

var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
      'uid': "valueAxis",
      'type': "Measure",
      'values': ["products"]
    }), 
    feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
      'uid': "categoryAxis",
      'type': "Dimension",
      #'values': ["Failed Tests"]
    });
oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis);
oVizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis);
```

So, instead of **name: "components",** it has to be **name: "products",**. I hope it can help someone in the future.